# How can a smart contract be triggered from an API get request?

Tags: dapp-development, oracles, dapp-design, architecture

I am working on a basic dApp architecture and I need one of the smart contracts to be triggered by the user which will pass a consumer API key (private and needs to stay private) to an Oracle that will check API state and return a value and based on this value this contract will send a transaction to the second contract. The only concern here is the privacy regarding the consumer API key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions -

1. You can use your own custom adapter, and hardcode the API Key in the backend.
2. Use [Adapter.js](https://market.link/adapters/ec3acd6a-57ef-4d3f-879d-8eaaefff1246) where you can execute arbitrary javascript code via chainlink oracles. It also has an option to securely store any secret variables and can only be accessed by the contract you specify, thus preventing exposure and unauthorised access.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The API key needs to be variable so each time will pass a different API key through user input. Can this be achieved with your second solution?

Comment: In that case, you can encrypt the API key every time and store the decrypting key in the Adapter.js server (or custom adapter)

Comment: I was looking for a decentralized solution, where the user doesn't need to trust anyone with their private API key. Is it possible to run this computation and encryption on client side? The flow would be web app frontend/mobile app as input - smart contract - oracle - private API.

Comment: Yes, you can use the public key to encrypt the API key on client side and decrypt it using the private key stored in the adapter

Comment: I am still trying to figure this out. Is it possible to pass a different API key to the Oracle each time you use the application? Could you help with this architecture? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. Create a public-key private key pair and store the private key in the adapterjs server or custom adapter. When you want to send an API key, encrypt it using the public key and pass it to the oracle. The adapter will then decrypt it using the API key.